# How to get Environment Variables in AWS Lambda C#

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, .net-core-3.1

I'm making an AWS Lambda, never done it before.

The Lambda was created using the Empty AWS Lambda template in Visual Studio 2019, .Net Core 3.1

I read that, in order to use the environment variables, I need to put in the file `aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json` the key `"environment-variables": "key=value"`

And in order to use it I would need to use the following:

```
string myVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("key");
```

but it is returning null, as a matter of fact if I execute the `GetEnvironmentVariables()` is returning other variables except the ones in the defaults json.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It works for me. I have `"environment-variables": "demo1=Foobar;demo2=Foobaz"` in `aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json` and I can get both their values with `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()`.